# Json and Bundle resource Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, bundle

I can access and display a file from the Xcode bundle like this:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

Now what I want to do is fill in the names of the file using this JSON which does fetch me the correct name:

```
self.localFileName = [BT_strings getJsonPropertyValue:self.screenData.jsonVars:@"localFileName":@""];
```

How do I put these two thing together so I can call the Bundled file using the JSON name?

Here is the whole thing:

```
//
//  ReaderDemoController.m
//  PDFViewer
//
//  Created by C. A. Beninati on 5/21/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//
//BT imports
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "JSON.h"
#import "BT_strings.h"
#import "testapp_appDelegate.h"
#import "BT_fileManager.h"
#import "BT_color.h"
#import "BT_viewUtilities.h"
#import "BT_downloader.h"
#import "BT_item.h"
#import "BT_debugger.h"
#import "BT_viewControllerManager.h"

#import "ReaderDemoController.h"
#import "ReaderViewController.h"

@interface ReaderDemoController ()<ReaderViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ReaderDemoController
@synthesize localFileName;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{ [BT_debugger showIt:self:@"ZZZZZZZZZZ!!!"];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.localFileName = [BT_strings getJsonPropertyValue:self.screenData.jsonVars:@"localFileName":@""];

    self.localFileName = @""; // added this to make it work!!

    NSString *file=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:self.localFileName ofType:@"pdf"];

    ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:file password:nil];

    if (document != nil)
    {
        ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
        readerViewController.delegate = self;

        readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

        [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
    }

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}




- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Am I on the right track?  NSString *file=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:self.localFileName ofType:@"pdf"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the correct file name from "self.localFilename", then you need to do nothing but pass it to your file as :

NSString *file=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:self.localFileName ofType:@"pdf"];

Comment: Thanks! it's working now. Here is the code. It wasn't working because I needed to add self.localFileName = @"";   I edited my code up top.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Now my next problem is when I leave this screen I still have an underlying screen showing. it doesn't just go back to my menu list.

Comment: New Problem! It seems the code is calling the same PDF file each time. any ideas? thank you

Comment: Can u print the name of the file which you get from JSON "self.localFileName" each time, is it coming correctly?

Comment: Yes I am seeing the JSON "self.localFileName" calling the correct name. But the reader keeps loading the same file even when the JSON "self.localFileName" is different.

Comment: Ok got it. Changed "PDF " to nil and all seems to be working!